# Extract numbers from string as numeric or dates in R

Tags: r, dataset, numeric, hdf5, stringr

I am working with some hdf5 data sets. However, the dates are stored in the file and no hint of these dates from the file name. The attribute file consists of day of the year, month of the year, day  of the month and year columns. 
I would like to pull out data to create time series identity for each of the files i.e.year month date format that can be used for time series.
A sample of the data can be downloaded here:

[ ftp://l5eil01.larc.nasa.gov/tesl1l2l3/TES/TL3COD.003/2007.08.31/TES-Aura_L3-CO_r0000006311_F01_09.he5 ]

There is an attribute group file and a data group file.
I use the **R** library "rhdf5" to explore the hdf5 files. E.g

```
CO1<-h5ls ("TES-Aura_L3-CO_r0000006311_F01_09.he5")
Attr<-h5read("TES-Aura_L3-CO_r0000006311_F01_09.he5","HDFEOS INFORMATION/coremetadata")
Data<-h5read("TES-Aura_L3-CO_r0000006311_F01_09.he5", "HDFEOS\SWATHS\ColumnAmountNO2\Data Fields\ColumnAmountNO2Trop")
```

The Attr when read consist of a long string with the only required information being "2007-08-31" which is the date of acquisition. I have been able to extract this using the Stringr library:

```
regexp <- "([[:digit:]]{4})([-])([[:digit:]]{2})([-])([[:digit:]]{2})"
Date<-str_extract(Attr,pattern=regexp)
```

which returns the Date as:

```
"2007-08-31"
```

The only problem left now is that the Date isnt recognised as numeric or date. How do I change this as I need to bind the Date with the data for all days to create a time series (more like an identifier as the data sets are irregular), please? a sample of how it looks after extracting the dates from string and binding with the CO values for each date is below

```
       Dates        CO3b        
[1,] "2011-03-01" 1.625811e+18
[2,] "2011-03-04" 1.655504e+18
[3,] "2011-03-11" 1.690428e+18
[4,] "2011-03-15" 1.679871e+18
[5,] "2011-03-17" 1.705987e+18
[6,] "2011-03-17" 1.661198e+18
[7,] "2011-03-17" 1.662694e+18
[8,] "2011-03-20" 1.520328e+18
[9,] "2011-03-21" 1.510642e+18
[10,] "2011-03-21" 1.556637e+18
```

However, **R** recognises these dates as character and not as date. I need to convert them to a time series I can work with.

Comment: just to clarify, you want to convert Date, which is currently a string, into a date object?

Comment: Yes DMT. For the list, I have extracted them e.g, "2007-10-02" "2007-10-04" "2007-10-07". I need to convert these extracted dates into a format where R recognisies it as dates not just characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach not using string extraction. If you know how long your time series should be, which you should based on the length of your dataset and knowledge of its periodicity, you could just create a regular date series and then add that into a data.frame with other variables of interest. Assuming you have daily data the below would work. Obviously your length.out would be different.

```
d1 <- ISOdate(year=2007,month=8,day=31)
d2 <- as.Date(format(seq(from=d1,by="day",length.out=10),"%Y-%m-%d"))
[1] "2007-08-31" "2007-09-01" "2007-09-02" "2007-09-03" "2007-09-04" "2007-09-05" "2007-09-06" "2007-09-07" "2007-09-08" "2007-09-09"
class(d2)
[1] "Date"
```

**Edit of Original:**

Oh I see. Well after reading in your new data example the below worked for me. It was a pretty straight forward transform. cheers

```
library(magrittr) # Needed for the pipe operator %>% it makes it really easy to string steps together.

    dateData

            Dates     CO3b
    1  2011-03-01 1.63e+18
    2  2011-03-04 1.66e+18
    3  2011-03-11 1.69e+18
    4  2011-03-15 1.68e+18
    5  2011-03-17 1.71e+18
    6  2011-03-17 1.66e+18
    7  2011-03-17 1.66e+18
    8  2011-03-20 1.52e+18
    9  2011-03-21 1.51e+18
    10 2011-03-21 1.56e+18

    dateData %>% sapply(class) # classes before transforming (character,numeric)

    dateData[,1] <- as.Date(dateData[,1]) # Transform to date

    dateData %>% sapply(class) # classes after transforming (Date,numeric)

    str(dateData) # one more check
    'data.frame': 10 obs. of  2 variables:
     $ Dates: Date, format: "2011-03-01" "2011-03-04" "2011-03-11" "2011-03-15" ...
     $ CO3b : num  1.63e+18 1.66e+18 1.69e+18 1.68e+18 1.71e+18 ...
```

Comment: Nice idea, miles2know. Unfortunately, the dates are random with some seasons having daily and some 3 times weekly data, so I can't just generate a sequence. It has to be Tue date extracted from the file.

Comment: Hi Miles2know, I just added a bit more information to the question. Hope it helps express my need better.

Comment: Hi...I also notice above that you talked about using cbind. This is really for matrix like structures which must be atomic (all the same data types). So when you cbind a date and numeric it will coerce your date into a numeric. If you need to combine different data types which you do best to use a data.frame...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've already done all the hard work!  Based off your comment, here's how you could take it across the finish line.

From your comment, seems like you have the strings in a good format.  Given that your variable is named date, simply go

```
 dateObjects<-as.Date(Date)   #where Date is your variable
```

and either the single value or vector of character strings (as the format you gave in the comment) will now be date objects, which you could use with a library like zoo to create time series.

If your strings are not necessarily in the format you've described, then refer to the following link to see how to format other string forms as dates.

http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html

Given your example data frame you can create a time series in the following way, using the package zoo.

```
library(zoo)
datavect<-as.zoo(df$CO3b)
index(datavect)<-as.Date(df$Date)
```

here we take your CO data, covert it to a zoo object, then assign the appropriate date to each entry, converting it from a character to a date object.  Now if you print datavect, you'll see each data entry attached to a date.  This allows you to take advantage of zoo methods, such as merge and window.

Comment: Thanks DMT. When I use the as.Date prompt, it still retains the inverted commas with one method and with the other, the dates look have numbers like "15432" once I cbind with other columns.

Comment: @JokeO. Not sure what you mean by inverted commas, can you give an example of the input and output?  It probably means you need to specify a format.  Also date objects in R are stored as integers, being the number of days from the seed Date in R which is 1970-01-01.  It's still your date.    You'll see that if you run class(yourVariable).

Comment: It returns "2012-04-16" whih R recognises as class character and not numeric or date. how do i ensure it doesnt covert to number of days from set seed date? i hope to create a time series with the dates as the columns

Comment: Hi DMT, I just added a bit more information to the question. Hope it helps.

Comment: @JokeO. Just added an example for making a time series, you're pretty much there.  Hopefully above is a typo and you meant a time series where the dates are rows, which is typically how they are represented